# Dynamic restrictions in SQLAlchemy Core query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to write a query where I can dynamically pass various restrictions to SQLA Core.  For example, I want to be able to specify on a `SELECT` query `WHERE color = 'blue'` or not specify that, dynamically. It might be nice to pass in a `{'color': 'blue'}` restrictions-dict, or maybe there's a more standard way.

I have read the tutorial and API documentation, but I'm wondering:

What would be an idiomatic contract for dynamic restrictions in SQLA Core, and how would it be implemented?

---

Comment: That'd depend on what you're doing and how. In general there's nothing stopping you from passing around `Select`s and applying [`where()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.where) as needed. You might find [`literal_column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) handy, if you wish to use such dicts as you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build your query dynamically without any problem. For instance, you can do:

```
query = select([table])
for key, value in params.iteritems():
    query = query.where(table.columns[key] == value)

print conn.execute(query).fetchall()
```

where `params` is just a dictionary of restrictions such as `{'column': 'value'}`. This will produce a query in which all the *where* clauses are chained with AND. Of course, if you need more complex *where* clauses the construction of the query can be a bit more difficult.

A working example:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData, Table

# create engine and connection
DB_URI = "mysql+mysqldb://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/database?charset=utf8mb4"
engine = create_engine(DB_URI, convert_unicode=True, echo=False)
conn = engine.connect()

# create table
metadata = MetaData()
pieces_table = Table('pieces', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('size', String(60)),
    Column('color', String(60)),
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

# insert data
conn.execute(pieces_table.insert(), [
    {'size': 'small', 'color': 'blue'},
    {'size': 'large', 'color': 'blue'},
    {'size': 'small', 'color': 'red'},
])

# query data

def build_query(table, params):
    query = select([table])
    for key, value in params.iteritems():
        query = query.where(table.columns[key] == value)
    return query

params = {
    'size': 'large',
    'color': 'blue',
}
query = build_query(pieces_table, params)
print conn.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: what if I want those query chained in "Or" ?